I think it's a good idea, isn't it?

I think it's a good idea(maybe a short pause here), isn't it?


I think he likes it, doesn't he?

Are these two sentences commonly used in spoken English? Or how would native speakers say?
Thank you.
(The rising intonation in a tag question indicates uncertainty, while the falling intonation suggests certainty.)

Questions about "is this okay" do best when you explain why you think it might not be okay. An answer that just says "sure" isn't very helpful.

A recently retired presenter on the BBC Radio4 Today programme drove me to distraction by her inability to ask a straight question. Her style was to make a statement and then ask the guest to confirm it. (Isn't it, didn't they, wasn't it?) I don't encourage you to follow suit except on occasion to make a point.

The final phrase re-examines the accuracy of the "I think" part of the sentence. For that reason, the examples you provided look a little off.
"Don't you" would be the most natural way to check whether the listener finds your opinion to be accurate.
"I think it's a good idea, don't you?"
"I think he likes it, don't you?"
You could also use "do you?" (and an emphasis on "I") to give a stronger indication of doubt about your own thoughts, and a genuine desire for the listener to correct you if they disagree.
You also have the option of just dropping "I think" from the sentence entirely because the final clause already suggests to the listener that you are stating your opinion. When you do this, the final clause properly re-examines the main point of the sentence instead of the "I think".
"It's a good idea, isn't it?"
"He likes it, doesn't he?"

I was composing a comment saying more or less the same thing when I saw your answer.

All the parts of the US I'm familiar with use "don't you", but at least on British TV, "isn't it" is common for the same purpose. Perhaps an actual Brit can chime in what they hear in daily life.

The OP said: The rising intonation in a tag question indicates uncertainty, while the falling intonation suggests certainty.
It's a good idea, isn't it? [expected answer: Yes, it is]
COMPARE:
It isn't a good idea, is it? [expected answer: No, it isn't]
I think he likes it, doesn't he?   [expected answer: Yes, he does]
COMPARE
He doesn't like it, does he? [expected answer: No, he doesn't]
It's not the falling or rising intonation of the tag. The speaker's attitude comes from the declarative statement and the negative tag or a negative statement and positive tag. Both those are asked with certain answers the speaker expects to hear.
Rising intonation of a tag in a sentence like this:
He likes it, doesn't he? just re-inforces the idea even more of the expected answer, Yes, he does. Rising intonation of the tag emphasizes even more what the speaker expects to hear.
[please note: I left the I think out to simplify showing the main idea here. It does not change what happens with tags. ]
